# Python glob matching file names?

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to use the `glob` module to make a list of all the Markdown files in my directory whose file paths contain either the strings `abcd` or `test`.

I know that this is successfully printing all the files in the directory:

```py
print(glob.glob('**/*.md', recursive=True))
```

However, I want it to only match filepaths such as `/home/users/a/abcd/one.md` or `/home/users/b/test/two.md` or `/home/users/c/subdir/test_or_abcd/three.md`. I want it to *not* match filepaths like `/home/users/a/other/result.md`.

However, when I try to do this, it doesn't work:

```py
print(glob.glob('**/*{abcd,test}.md', recursive=True))
```

Any suggestions or ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure glob can do alternates.

Comment: Ugly solution: `list(filter(lambda x: any(y in x for y in ("abcd", "test")), glob.glob("**/*.md", recursive=True)))`. A little too broad and catches somethings it shouldn't. You can also filter with regex which would be better at getting exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Do it as many filters u have ?

```py
files = [
    *glob.glob('**/*abcd.md', recursive=True),
    *glob.glob('**/*test.md', recursive=True)
]
```